# Is there an efficient way to do basic math on very large numbers?

Tags: python, math, largenumber

I have a long list of very large numbers (all 30+ in length), and I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to perform basic operations with them. I know, for example, that I can run something like

```
total=sum(list)
```

or

```
for n in range(len(list)):
    total*=list[n]
```

and Python will eventually spit out the answer. I suspect, however, that there is a more efficient way to perform operations on large numbers that I just don't know about, being a bit of a newbie.

Comment: so a list of 30 numbers, or some numbers that are 30+ digits?

Comment: Break them to number of pieces and then do individual sum and final sum. That is quicker than to sum each of them

Comment: I just did a `sum` on a hundred ninety digit numbers, and it delivered the result near-instantaneously. Are you sure you actually need to worry about efficiency?

Comment: Your second is better done as `reduce(operator.mul, li)` but your first one's not getting any faster in native python.  Move up to `numpy` if you need better performance.

Comment: If you're concerning yourself with this type of optimisation question then you are probably using the wrong language.

Comment: @Daniel: nonsense, since Python's developers have already done the optimization *for* you, and you don't even need to find your own bignum library.

Comment: @MarcB Both, somewhat. The list contains an arbitrary number of numbers and all of the numbers have at least 30 digits.

Comment: There's almost always a more efficient way but you are already getting native performance for bigint addition and multiplication. You will be hard-pressed to do significantly better.

Answer (score -1):

you can use [vectorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(parallel_computing)) for computing some of the basic operation which uses the linear algebra libraries, these libraries would be find in any programming language.
for example if you want to compute `a*b + c*d + e*f + g*h`, you can use the multiplication of two vectors, A & B like this (it's not a piece of code):

> A = |a c e g|
>   B =
>   |b|
>   |d|
>   |f |
>   |g|
>   a*b + c*d + e*f + g*h = A*B

Comment: Most linear algebra libraries don't handle arbitrary-precision integers.